# Add C function as value to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, dictionary, objective-c-blocks

Upon receiving an `NSString`, I would like to call a specific code block. I figured an `NSDictionary` would be best for associating these. Simplified, I'm using something like:

MyProtocol.h:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

typedef void (^Handler)(id<MyProtocol> obj, id data);

@end
```

MyClass.h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyProtocol>

- (void)aMethodWithString:(NSString *)string andData:(id)data;

@end
```

MyClass.m:

```
@interface MyClass ()

void myCommandHandler(id<MyProtocol> obj, id data); // matches signature defined in protocol

@end

@implementation MyClass

void myCommandHandler(id<MyProtocol> obj, id data)
{
    // ...
}

- (void)aMethodWithString:(NSString *)string andData:(id)data
{
    static NSDictionary<NSString *, Handler> *handler;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    // don't allocate this dictionary every time the function is called
    dispatch_once(&onceToken,
        ^{  
            handler =
                @{
                    @"MyCommand":myCommandHandler,
                };
        });

    // ... error checking, blah blah ...

    Handler block;
    if ((block = handler[string]))
        { block(self, data); }
}
@end
```

Using this, I get an error in the dictionary literal construction:

> Collection element of type 'void (__strong id<MyProtocol>, __strong id)' is not an Objective-C object`

So how can I include a C function or block reference in the dictionary? There will be quite a few larger complex functions to be defined, so it would be *very* much preferred to not have all of them defined inside the dictionary literal itself (a technique I know will work).

--

Also, I'm not sure what's considered proper style here: (1) I originally had the dictionary declaration outside of any method body at the file scope (without the `dispatch_once(...)`) which generates the same error, but I thought maybe it would be easier for others to see what's going on by (2) including it in the only method that uses that dictionary. Is one style preferred over the other for any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Handler` type is a block type, not a function pointer type. If you had declared it using `*` instead of `^`, it would be a function pointer type.

Your `myCommandHandler` function is, of course, a function, not a block. Your comment is wrong. It does **not** match type `Handler`.

Function pointers are not Objective-C object pointers. Functions are not objects. Blocks **are** Objective-C objects, but you're not actually using any blocks here. (You've just declared a typedef for one, but you're not actually using it.)

You could use blocks and store them in your dictionary. The blocks could either contain the desired code or call a function or method which does.

Comment: That clarified a lot! I've left the typedef for my block, and changed the function declaration of `myCommandHandler` to a block declaration with definition: `static const Handler myCommandHandler = ^void(id<MyProtocol> obj, id data) { ... };`. With this, I can store `myCommandHandler` in an NSDictionary. This seems cleaner than wrapping the C function call in a useless block object. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

A C function address is not an Objective-C object, and an `NSDictionary` can only store the latter.

A C function address is just a pointer, to wrap a C pointer as an object you use `NSValue` and its class method `valueWithPointer`.

To get the pointer value back from the `NSValue` object you use the instance method `pointerValue`. Before you can use the extracted pointer you must cast it to your function type.

HTH

Comment: You could also wrap the C function in a block and store the block in the dictionary. It would probably be easier.

Comment: For completeness, you could also use a (properly configured) [`NSMapTable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmaptable?language=objc), but `NSValue` or blocks are probably better for most devs.

Comment: My immediate attempt at using`NSValue` to wrap my function pointer was resulting in an address exception when calling the member `pointerValue` of it. The other posted answer seemed a more natural solution, so I committed to it instead